# искажение звука при использовании библиотеки pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet

я еще начинающий в питоне и хотел сделать простую програмку которая бы при нажатии клавиши вопспроизводила звук. в первый раз аудиозапись воспроизводится нормально, а потом звук начинает нереально искажатся и начинается какая то рекурсия. использую библиотеки pyglet, keyboard

```
    import keyboard
    import pyglet
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('l'):
            song = keyboard.
            continue
        if keyboard.is_pressed('o'):
            break
```

Comment: Вы хотите реализовать меню, которое при нажатии на `l` запускает музыку, а если на `o`, то останавливает?

Comment: ну да пытался сделать

Comment: Оцените, пожалуйста, ответ, если он вас устраивает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вариант плеера:

```
import pyglet
 
# Ширина Окна
width = 500
   
# Высота окна
height = 500
   
title = "Плеер"
   
# Создаем окно
window = pyglet.window.Window(width, height, title)
 
 
# путь к файлу
vidPath ="файл.mp3"
 
# Создание медиа плеера
player = pyglet.media.Player()
 
# Создание исходного объекта
source = pyglet.media.StreamingSource()
 
# Загрузка носителя из источника
MediaLoad = pyglet.media.load(vidPath)
 
# Добавление этот носитель в очередь
player.queue(MediaLoad)
 
# Воспроизведение видео
player.play()
 
# Окно
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    if player.source and player.source.video_format:
        player.get_texture().blit(0, 0)
         
         
# Обработка события нажатия на клавиатуре
@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifier):
    if symbol == pyglet.window.key.L:
        print("Пауза")
        player.pause()
         
    if symbol == pyglet.window.key.O:
        print("Продолжить")
        player.play()


pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: спасибо попробую, не знал что в pyglet можно проверять нажатие клавиш. у меня вопрос, а вы не можете сказать где можно больше узнать про библиотеку pyglet

Comment: Есть документации для `pyglet` на английском языке: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Также можете посмотреть на русском языке: https://russianblogs.com/article/91581069584/

Comment: спасибо большое